# Unable to use has_goog_key() in R

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

Below simple lines before start to use 'ggmap'

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
library(devtools)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggmap)
library(gmapsdistance)

api_key = Sys.getenv("A_GOOGLE_API_KEY")
register_google(key = api_key)
set.api.key(api_key)

has_goog_key()
```

It returns:

```
Error in has_goog_key() : could not find function "has_goog_key"
```

What went wrong, and how can I check if the given Goole API key is valid?

Comment: It looks like `has_goog_key` might be a function in a different `ggmap` package (`devtools::install_github("fresques/ggmap")`). Have you tried `has_google_key` instead?

Comment: @HaydenY. wow! that's the solution! can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_goog_key` is a function in a different `ggmap package`, which you can find via `devtools::install_github("fresques/ggmap")`. In the package you're using, the equivalent function would be `has_google_key`.